# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'Event_event' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key:

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my Event Model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    TIMEZONES = tuple(zip(pytz.all_timezones, pytz.all_timezones))
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONES)
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)
```

and my session model

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date=models.DateField()
    end_date=models.DateField()
    speaker=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)
```

I get an error when I create a test.
What should I do in the session section?
this is my test code

```
class CreateTest(APITestCase):
    def test_create_event(self):
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/event/create'
        data = Event.objects.create(
            name="deneme 5",
            start_date="2020-05-23",
            end_date="2020-05-26",
            timezone="Etc/GMT",
            session_id='1'
            )
        response = self.client.post(url,data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: id should be `int` not `str`

Comment: I did int but did not

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because, you haven't any `Session` record which has id 1. You must create `Session` object before create `Event` object and provide  this created session id to event object. In Django `APITestCase`, new empty database is created for all test functions all time.